# How do alpha particles excite the atoms in the zinc sulphide?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

I understand that when a photon is absorbed or when an electron collides with an atom the electrons may gain energy and become excited if the energy corresponds to a difference in energy levels. In the gold foil experiment the zinc sulphide screen produced a flash of light when the alpha particles hit it. What I’m confused about is how can an atom like an alpha particle collide with another atom and excite it? Wouldn’t it ionise the zinc sulphide atoms?

Comment: You say "the gold foil experiment" like there has been exactly one experiment involving gold foil in the history of science. (Or, in other words, this question needs a whole lot more context.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. This was in the Geiger-Marsden experiments

Comment: "The Geiger-Marsden experiments" is less ambiguous, but far from clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading Jackson, "Classical Electrodynamics"...not the whole book, but the part on charged particles passing by another charged particle. Because the forces goes as $1/r^2$, and the volume of influence at closest approach ($r=b$) goes as $r^2 dr dl$, there is no maximum impact parameter, in theory. Nevertheless, the alpha isn't hitting the atom, it influences the atomic electrons from a distance (which may be inside the orbitals, but that doesn't matter): it ionizes the molecule.

Now I am not familiar with inorganic molecular scintillators (since we always used plastics, like gatorade bottle seals in the US, or something like tonic water: def. shine a UV light into tonic water)...but during deionization, the electron falls through states that emit a distinctive color of light.

Now in organic scintillators, the molecules can just be excited to states that emit characteristic photons (fluorescence aka 'black light') or meta-stable states that can take hours to decay (delayed fluorescence aka phosphorescence, aka glow-in-the-dark).

You should readout those phenomena on wiki, and maybe find to details about zinc-sulphide.

Comment: But if the alpha ionised the atoms wouldn’t they not be excited? Are there other ways of exciting atoms without colliding them with electrons or having them absorb photons?

Comment: It's probably molecular excitation. There's a perturbing field, that couples states, a transition happens. No need for photons, and if they are ionized, they recapture electrons in an excited state. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillation_counter

Comment: Interesting, thank you!